# How do I figure out whether this is a bug or how do I debug what is trying to access my webcam?

Tags: malware, privacy, anti-virus, webcam

Similar question, which has a different question (since my AV doesn't even know the process ID or similar): [Antivirus warns about processes trying to access my webcam](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/195049/antivirus-warns-about-processes-trying-to-access-my-webcam)

I am using ESET Internet Security and suddenly the AV started popping up with warnings that someone is trying to access my webcam with quite a few programs, out of which quite a handful doesn't even need a webcam at all.

The list of programs that tried to supposedly use my webcam:

- Steam
- Chromium
- Discord
- Twitch (the desktop app)

How can I further debug whether this is just my AV solution acting up or it's actually a rogue process trying to access my webcam?

I can't seem to find a log of my AV which would uphold this information with a process ID or similar...

Comment: Are you sure those things *aren't* trying to access your webcam? Those programs certainly *can* use a webcam.

Comment: I am sure that they **SHOULDN'T** access the webcam at that time when the notification pops up.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with webcam permissions on Windows, but *actively using* the webcam -- which would turn on the light and usually only one app can do at a time -- might be different from *checking for access* to the webcam, which apps may do in the background in order to, for example decide whether to display / gray out a menu item .

Comment: If your text editor or solitaire game was asking for webcam / microphone access, that would be alarming. Something that can legitimately use webcam like Twitch / Discord / Zoom / browser asking for it on startup or in the background is a lot less alarming to me.

Comment: Well, Steam certainly doesn't use a webcam anywhere. As well Twitch doesn't AFAIK, since it doesn't stream by itself - it's only a client for viewing streamed content.

Comment: Fair. If you're not expecting it to need the webcam ever, that's a bit suspicious indeed! Does the AV let you block it and forget about it?

Comment: It does, but my main point is figuring out what API call or something similar happens in the background. I'm theorizing it might a "rogue" (I'm calling it that because logically it's rogue) telemetry component from Microsoft like from the tagged similar question, but the application itself and not the process in the question is getting displayed which completely destroys this theory...

Comment: Apps could use an embeded browser, that's a common way to push formatted text to a user from a server without updating a binary (recompiling/upgrading). That embeded browser is probably a scaled-down "real" browser, which ships with stuff to reach webcams, which triggers your detection.